# Python Create new columns based on other column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF:

| Fecha | xG | xGA | Home | Away | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 1.53 | 0.45 | América | Cruz Azul | 0:0 |
| 2022-04-24 | 1.46 | 0.47 | Tigres UANL | América | 0:2 |
| 2022-04-21 | 1.40 | 0.43 | América | León | 2:0 |
| 2022-04-16 | 2.44 | 0.65 | Club Tijuana | América | 1:3 |

I want to create two new columns named HomeXG and AwayXG where the values are taken from the xG and xGA columns under the condition that if America is the home team the xG becomes HomeXG and if they are away xG is used for AwayXG.

Expected output:

| Fecha | xG | xGA | Home | Away | Score | HomeXG | AwayXG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 1.53 | 0.45 | América | Cruz Azul | 0:0 | 1.53 | 0.45 |
| 2022-04-24 | 1.46 | 0.47 | Tigres UANL | América | 0:2 | 0.47 | 1.46 |
| 2022-04-21 | 1.40 | 0.43 | América | León | 2:0 | 1.40 | 0.43 |
| 2022-04-16 | 2.44 | 0.65 | Club Tijuana | América | 1:3 | 0.65 | 2.44 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) on a 2D slice of the DataFrame:

```
df[['HomexG', 'AwayxG']] = df[['xG', 'xGA']].where(df['Home'].eq('América'),
                                                   df[['xGA', 'xG']].values)
```

*NB. the second argument of `where` must be a numpy array to avoid index alignment!*

output:

```
        Fecha    xG   xGA          Home       Away Score  HomexG  AwayxG
0  2022-05-01  1.53  0.45       América  Cruz Azul   0:0    1.53    0.45
1  2022-04-24  1.46  0.47   Tigres UANL    América   0:2    0.47    1.46
2  2022-04-21  1.40  0.43       América       León   2:0    1.40    0.43
3  2022-04-16  2.44  0.65  Club Tijuana    América   1:3    0.65    2.44
```

Comment: This code only works correctly when America is away. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that there are case where neither Home/Away is América? What should happen then?

Comment: No, sorry. On all América is always one of the 2. Now when I run the code I get the correct xG when América appears away. When they are at home the xG values are reversed.

Comment: You mean the `HomexG`? Isn't it precisely what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah. The output you have on the answer is correct. But when I run the code row 0 and 2 are reversed where HomexG is 0.45 and AwayxG is 1.53.

Comment: I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), solution testing only `Home` column, it means `América` should me in `Away` for non matched rows:

```
df[['HomexG', 'AwayxG']] = np.where(df['Home'].eq('América').to_numpy()[:, None], 
                                    df[['xG','xGA']], df[['xGA','xG']])
print (df)
        Fecha    xG   xGA          Home       Away Score  HomexG  AwayxG
0  2022-05-01  1.53  0.45       América  Cruz Azul   0:0    1.53    0.45
1  2022-04-24  1.46  0.47   Tigres UANL    América   0:2    0.47    1.46
2  2022-04-21  1.40  0.43       América       León   2:0    1.40    0.43
3  2022-04-16  2.44  0.65  Club Tijuana    América   1:3    0.65    2.44
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['HomexG', 'AwayxG'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"